# Unable to return a type struct in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, struct, doubly-linked-list

I have the following struct and function. After allocating a 2D array, I want to return it but for some reason I keep getting the error: "warning: returning ‘int **’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘Array *’ {aka ‘struct array *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"

```
typedef struct array
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int *data;
} Array;


    Array *array_create(int n1, int n2)
    {
    
     int **arr = malloc(n1 * sizeof(int*));
      for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
      {
       arr[i] = malloc(n2*sizeof(int));
      }
    
      Array values = {n1, n2, *arr};
    
        return values;
    }
```

Here's some code from the main function for some clarity:

```
{
    Array *arr = array_create(4, 4);

    int cnt = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            array_set(arr, i, j, cnt++);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You claim that `array_create ` will return an `Array *`. The function eventually returns `return arr;`. If we trace back where `arr` was defined, we find `int **arr`. And `int **` is not `Array *`.

Comment: @Cheatah Pardon me, I must have written made an error by typing return arr instead of return values. However, despite values being of type Array, I'm still getting the same error when returning it.

Comment: @Adele Please post a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that details the *exact* code you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to return a pointer to your struct, so you have to malloc it first:

```
const Array *values = malloc(sizeof(*values));
return values
```

And if you want your Array to be const you need to change the function declaration:

```
const Array *array_create(int n1, int n2)
```

and the variable declaration in the main function:

```
const Array *arr = array_create(4, 4);
```

Comment: rather `Array *values = malloc(sizeof(*values));`

Comment: Is it possible though to allocate a 2D array for a type struct? I thought you could only do that with a variable of type int, can't seem to find a way to do it with a type struct.

Comment: @Adele You can simply do the same thing with a struct, for example `Array values[5][5]` is just as valid as `int values[5][5]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you do not allocate a 2D array only array of pointers.
2. Use the correct types of sizes (`size_t`)
3. Your pointer has the wrong type.

I would do it different away to avoid complicated malloc patterns.

```
typedef struct array
{
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    int data[];
} Array;

Array *array_alloc(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) + rows * cols * sizeof(array -> data[0]));
    if(array)
    {
        array -> rows = rows;
        array -> cols = cols;
    }
    return array;
}


#define ARR(var) ((int (*)[var -> cols])(var -> data))

int main(void)
{
    Array *a = array_alloc(10,20);

    for(size_t row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < 20; col++)
        {
            ARR(a)[row][col] = row *1000 + col;
        }
    }

    for(size_t row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < 20; col++)
        {
            printf("[%5d] ", ARR(a)[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```